# jquery export asp table to excel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i was reading from this blog
http://growingtech.blogspot.in/2012/10/export-html-to-excel-using-jquery-and.html

the aspx page is below:

```
       <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="exportPage.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="exportPage" %>

       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <head runat="server">
            <title></title>

         <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function exportexcel() {
        var data = $("#toReport").html();
        data = escape(data);

        $('body').prepend("<form method='post' action='exportPage.aspx' style='top:-3333333333px;' id='tempForm'><input type='hidden' name='data' value='" + data + "' ></form>");
        $('#tempForm').submit();
        $("tempForm").remove();

    }
    </script>


       </head>
      <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>

                <h2>
           Export
      </h2>

              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export"                    OnClientClick="exportexcel()" onclick="Button1_Click"  />
       <div id="toReport">
      <table>
      <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  <th>Email</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td>John</td>
  <td>44</td>
  <td>john@gmail.com</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Rambo</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>rambo@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>It's hot</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>test@hotmail.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </div>



</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and c# is below

```
          using System;
             using System.Collections.Generic;
          using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

        public partial class exportPage : System.Web.UI.Page
             {
             protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {

   }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      string data = Request.Form["data"];
      data = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);
      Response.Clear();
      Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",   "attachment;filename=report.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(data);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
    }
```

i wonder where did I fail to pass the table data to excel? My jquery link seems to reference ok, but somwhow i ended up downloading an empty excel. thanks for any advice!

Comment: So what's the problem are you getting any exception ?

Comment: i ended up downloading an empty excel

Comment: why are you using a server side button to do the trick ?

Comment: good qustion, the orginal code is using a link, i will try if it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using a server side button and you are calling a JavaScript function before submitting your code but since both actions are running asynchronously there's no guaranty that the form data is populated before your form is being posted to the server.

Also you should know that submitting : `form method='post' action='exportPage.aspx'` will hit `exportPage.aspx` thus its PageLoad will be raised but the handler for your button `( Button1_Click)` will not hit.